# Create an UltraVnc SC server, that works like TeamViewer

Tags: remote-desktop, debian-squeeze, teamviewer, ultravnc

I would like to create an UltraVnc SC server on my root debian server that I can connect to from all my customer clients.

[I Download custom.zip here](http://www.uvnc.com/docs/uvnc-sc/73-howto-create.html) and try to create an exe with [this tutorial](http://www.uvnc.com/downloads/single-click/82-single-click-downloads.html) but failed ;)

It seems like [here is a step-by-step tutorial](http://www.uvnc.com/docs/uvnc-sc/76-how-to-setup-and-configure-a-custom-ultravnc-sc.html), but that page is so cluttered, it hurts my Eyes ;)

Is there an easy explanation to create a solution that works nearly like I used to use TeamViewer all the time?